# How to sort data frame with consecutive row numbers?

Tags: r

I made a contingency table and data frame as:

```
Countries <- table(data1$countries)
Countriesdf <- data.frame(Countries)
```

```
           Var1 Freq
1    Azerbaijan    1
2    Bangladesh  200 
3       Belarus   19
4       Bolivia   33
5        Brazil  115
```

I am trying to sort the data frame 'Countriesdf' by '$Freq' using the order function in R. The command returns sorted dataframe while keeping the original row numbers. I want consecutively numbered rows in sorted dataframe as 1,2,3,4.....

```
Countries_Asc <- order(Countriesdf$Freq)
Countries_Ordered <- Countries[Countries_Asc,]
```

```
            Var1 Freq
2    Bangladesh  200
5        Brazil  115
4       Bolivia   33
3       Belarus   19
1    Azerbaijan    1
```

I am expecting this result:

```
            Var1 Freq
1    Bangladesh  200
2        Brazil  115
3       Bolivia   33
4       Belarus   19
5    Azerbaijan    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the row names to `NULL`:

```r
df <- df[order(df$Freq, decreasing = T),] 
row.names(df) <- NULL

df
#         Var1 Freq
# 1 Bangladesh  200
# 2     Brazil  115
# 3    Bolivia   33
# 4    Belarus   19
# 5 Azerbaijan    1
```

This will happen automatically using `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df |>
  arrange(desc(Freq))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked.
`Countries_Ordered <- Countriesdf[order(Countriesdf$Freq, decreasing = TRUE),]`
`row.names(Countries_Ordered) <- NULL`
`Countries_Ordered`

Comment: Omg, does dplyr really do that.